# storing cookies in an array with javascript(or using cookie as an array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

Edit: 
I solved it somehow with PHP. Its so specific but I want to share it in case somebody needs it. First of all I didnt give any specific name as product_id for the cookie but I just give the variable of the product_id "$ftc2" which is clicked, shown as below

```
onclick=\"SetCookie('".$ftc2."', '".$ftc2."', 'expiry');
```

So whenever user clicks on any product, a new cookie is created with the name of the product_id like name=2 or name=32 whatever.

then I have created a foreach on the chart page as below

```
<?php foreach($_COOKIE as $cookies) { echo $cookies; } ?>
```

It displayes now all stored cookie values(in my case product ids) and now I can manipulate it as I want and display all products which is added to chart Maybe it is so easy and so common but somehow I couldnt find it out since morning = )) I hope it saves someone's hours

THE QUESTION WAS:

---

I am building an onlineshop and What I want to do is displaying all clicked products in showChart page.(a very simple page which shows you the products that you added to your chart by clicking on chart_icon). I have tried some several common methods but I couldnt manage to do it somehow. My last desperate try was creating this addToChart() function.

Since setting the cookie part works good I simplified the code and paste just the important parts (in my opinion). Any kind of help or suggestions would be appreciated. I dont expect anyone to write the code for me.

thanks in advance

```
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
        {
            $ftc = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_image");
            $ftc2 = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_id");
            $ftc3 = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_name");
            $ftc4 = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_preis");
            $ftc5 = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_old_preis");
            echo "<a href='details.php?product=".$ftc2."'><div class='products_list'>
            <img width='217px' height='323px' src='".$ftc."'/>
            <div class='alt_yazi2'><b>".$ftc3 ." &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp <font      

style='float:right;'>".$ftc4."TL &nbsp;&nbsp<b style='text-decoration:line-through; float:right;'>".$ftc5."TL </b></font></b></a>
    </br>
    <div id='sepet'><a id='cookie' onclick=\"SetCookie('"cookie_product"', '".$ftc2."', 'expiry');\" href='#'>
    <img width='35px' height='25px' src='images/cart_icon.png'/>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE BEGINS HERE

var today = new Date();
        var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

```
    function getCookieVal (offset) {
      var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
      if (endstr == -1) { endstr = document.cookie.length; }
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
      }

    function GetCookie (name) {
      var arg = name + "=";
      var alen = arg.length;
      var clen = document.cookie.length;
      var i = 0;
      while (i < clen) {
        var j = i + alen;
        if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) {
          return getCookieVal (j);
          }
        i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
        if (i == 0) break;
        }
      return null;
      }

    function SetCookie (name,value,expires,path,domain,secure) {

      document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
        ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
        ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
        ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
        ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");

      }

    document.getElementById(cookie).onclick = function addToChart()
            {
                var cookieValue = document.getElementById(cookie).value;
                var cookiearray = new Array();
                cookiearray = cookieValue.split(",");
                return cookiearray;

            }
```

Comment: Post the actual page source (after it's been generated as seen by View/Source in the borwser), not some templating language that most people who can help you here don't know.

Comment: I solved it somehow

Ok I have solved my problem with PHP. Its so specific but I want to share it in case somebody needs it.

First of all I didnt give any specific name as product_id for the cookie but I just give the variable of the product_id "$ftc2" which is clicked, shown as below

    onclick=\"SetCookie('".$ftc2."', '".$ftc2."', 'expiry');

So whenever user clicks on any product, a new cookie is created with the name of the product_id like name=2 or name=32 whatever.

Comment: then I have created a foreach on the chart page as below

    <?php 
    foreach($_COOKIE as $cookies)
      {
        echo $cookies;
       }
    
    ?>

It displayes now all stored cookie values(in my case product ids) and now I can manipulate it as I want and display all products which is added to chart 

Maybe it is so easy and so common but somehow I couldnt find it out since morning = ))
I hope it saves someone's hours

Comment: You can and should post your solution as an answer to this question(which you can accept later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have solved my problem with PHP. Its so specific but I want to share it in case somebody needs it.

First of all I didnt give any specific name as product_id for the cookie but I just give the variable of the product_id "$ftc2" which is clicked, shown as below

```
onclick=\"SetCookie('".$ftc2."', '".$ftc2."', 'expiry');
```

So whenever user clicks on any product, a new cookie is created with the name of the product_id like name=2 or name=32 whatever.

then I have created a foreach on the chart page as below

```
<?php 
foreach($_COOKIE as $cookies)
     {
             echo $cookies;
      }

?>
```

It displayes now all stored cookie values(in my case product ids) and now I can manipulate it as I want and display all products which is added to chart

Maybe it is so easy and so common but somehow I couldnt find it out since morning = ))